# enable my div with ng-show

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a button when i click on it i call a function but i want to enable my `div`, so i use `ng-show` but nothing is appear..?

***HTML:***

```
<br/><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="enableCompare()" ng-click="on_compare_plateformes($item)">Comparer</button>

<div class="row" ng-show="showme">
...
</div>
```

***JS:***

```
$scope.enableCompare = function () {
        return !($scope.myselectref && $scope.myselectcible);
    };

$scope.on_compare_plateformes = function () {
...
// here i set showme to true ..?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$scope.on_compare_plateformes = function () {
    $scope.showme = true; // or any other logic you want
};
```

You use the function to set the var `$scope.showme` rather than "return" the value

Answer (score 1):

set showme in controller to default

```
$scope.showme = false;
```

then in function:

```
$scope.on_compare_plateformes = function () {
  $scope.showme = !$scope.showme;
}
```

or `$scope.showme = true;` if you don't want to toggle

Answer (score 1):

angular has listeners always enabled so in your case just change the `showme` variable do the trick

```
$scope.showme=true;
```

Comment: because i use this function to enable my buton when i have selected value in my two list, see the enableCompare method